# look up table names in PSQL

Tags: psql

My DB has **a lot of tables** (Say 400+), and I only remember part of the name of the one I am looking for.

I know `\d` would show all the tables, but that's too much to look at. Is there some command to list all the tables whose names match the given regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

It's built in to psql, you can use wildcards in `\d`, `\dt`, etc, eg:

```
craig=> \dt test*
         List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------+-------+-------
 public | test      | table | craig
 public | testtable | table | craig
 public | testu     | table | craig
 public | testx     | table | craig
(4 rows)
```

You'll want to use `\dt` since `\d` will display *details* for each table, not just list the table.

You can do this with schemas too, eg:

```
\dt *.sometable
```

will list all tables named `sometable` in any schema.

Much more convenient than writing queries against `pg_class` joined to `pg_namespace`, or querying `information_schema`.

The usual globbing syntax is accepted, where `?` is any single character and `*` is zero or more characters. So `\dt ????` would list all tables with four-character names.

Multiple wildcards are permitted, eg:

```
craig=> \dt public.*e?t*
           List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  | Owner 
--------+--------------+-------+-------
 public | exclude_test | table | craig
 public | prep_test    | table | craig
 public | test         | table | craig
 public | testtable    | table | craig
 public | testu        | table | craig
 public | testx        | table | craig
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not very convenient unless you make it a proc, but;

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE SUBSTRING(tablename FROM '<regex>') <> '';
```

To make it more convenient, you can create and call a proc as;

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ft(TEXT) RETURNS SETOF pg_tables AS 
  'SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE SUBSTRING(tablename from $1) <> '''';'
LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM ft('.*oc.*')      -- Gets all tables matching `.*oc.*`
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3a2a7/3).

Comment: Remember to add 'tablename' if you just need the tablenames                `SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE SUBSTRING(tablename FROM '<regex>') <> '';`

Answer (score 0):

There is a table called `pg_tables` which has all table names in it.